# bash didnt work through php

Tags: php, bash, shell

Manually i am able to run this script and it writes in crontab. but when i execute the following script in php. it doesnt. But it says 'bash didn't work'.

```
'#!/bin/bash '."\n".'(crontab -l ; echo "13 * * * * /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/etools6/scheduler/etbat.sh" ) 2>&1 | grep -v "no crontab" | sort | uniq | crontab -';
```

Above code is stored in a file called batfile.sh

```
$batfile = batfile.sh;

chdir(getcwd());
shell_exec("chmod -R 777 ".getcwd().'/'.$batfile);
shell_exec("chmod +x ".getcwd().'/'.$batfile);
$output = shell_exec('/bin/bash ./'.$batfile) or die('bash didn't work');
echo $output;
```

I am not able to find solution for this on this forum thats the reason i am writing it here.

This portion is not getting executed through php

```
$output = shell_exec('/bin/bash ./'.$batfile) or die('bash didn't work');
```

Comment: What do you want to do ??

Comment: This portion is not getting executed

`$output = shell_exec('/bin/bash ./'.$batfile) or die('bash didn't work');`

Comment: Actually $batfile is not a filename or directory and the command chmod is run on file or directory

Comment: You seem to have the contents of a script in `batfile` but you never write it to a file anywhere.  Try just running it with `bash -c` if all the quoting is right, or write it to a file first and then execute that file

Comment: So, don't `die` and take a look at the error message, if any.

Comment: Now i have edited the question bit. I have those contents in a file called batfile.sh which is in the same directory.

Comment: How do i get that error?